# Finding the pivot of an Array- C Program

Tags: c, arrays, pivot

I have to find the pivot of a given array. Please tell me what is wrong with this implementation. It always returns -1.

```
int leftsum(int *nums, int index)
{
    int lsum=0;

        for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
            lsum += nums[i];
    return lsum;
}
int rightsum(int *nums, int index,int numsSize)
{
    int rsum=0;

    for(int i=index+1;i<=numsSize;i++)
        rsum += nums[i];
    return rsum;
}

int pivotIndex(int* nums, int numsSize) 
{ 
   for (int i=1;i<numsSize;i++)
   {
      if(leftsum(nums,i) == rightsum(nums,i,numsSize))  
         return i;
   }


   return -1;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the middle point of the sorted array?

Comment: for (int i=1;i<numsSize;i++)
Start i from 0 or make i<=numsSize.

Comment: What is the expected result if the left sum and the right sum are not exactly identical? What is the input you feed into that function?

Comment: Your right sum runs beyond the array: `for(int i=index+1;i<=numsSize;i++)`

Comment: @kiranBiradar Your second suggested option is likely to cause out of bounds access

Comment: Can yout post the array you are running the function on? Also what do you mean by `numsSize`? Is it the size of the array or the biggest index in the array?

Comment: Given an array of integers nums, write a method that returns the "pivot" index of this array.

We define the pivot index as the index where the sum of the numbers to the left of the index is equal to the sum of the numbers to the right of the index.

If no such index exists, we should return -1. If there are multiple pivot indexes, you should return the left-most pivot index.

Comment: numSize is the size of the array.

Answer (score 2):

This was a good chance for starting to learn debugging.

> ```
> int rightsum(int *nums, int index,int numsSize) {
>     int rsum=0;
>
>     for(int i=index+1;i<=numsSize;i++)
>         rsum += nums[i];
>     return rsum; }
> ```

Here condition in for loop should be `i<numsSize` and not `i<=numsSize`